# Aggregate, but function uses two columns

Tags: r

I'm sure this has been asked 1000 times, but I can't find the question, and can't figure it out.

I have a data.frame, with a location (a factor), a date, and a variable.

I want to find the date on which the variable is maximized, for each location.

```
df = data.frame(FAC = factor(rep(c("A","B","C"),each=5)), VAR = runif(15), DATE = rep(as.Date(c("2000-01-01","2000-01-02","2000-01-03","2000-01-04","2000-01-05"))))
```

I can easily (but messily) do this with a `for` loop:

```
df_summary = data.frame(FAC = levels(df$FAC),date=as.Date(character(1)))
for(i in seq_along(levels(df$FAC))){
  df_subset = subset(df,FAC == levels(df$FAC)[i])
  max_date = df_subset$DATE[which.max(df_subset$VAR)]
  df_summary$date[df_summary$FAC == levels(df$FAC)[i]] = max_date
}
```

But I imagine there's a 'nice' way either with `aggregate` or `dplyr`, but I can't figure it out.

My (failed) attempts:

```
aggregate(x=df$DATE,by=list(df$FAC),FUN=function(x) x[which.max(df$VAR)])
```

This doesn't work, because `df$VAR` isn't subset in the function.

And I don't really know how to use `dplyr` because I generally use base R.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `aggregate(VAR~FAC, df, \(x) df$DATE[which.max(x)])`

Comment: Can you explain what this does? I can see it works, but not sure how.

Comment: That is a base r solution. Perhaps the args make it clear: `aggregate(formula=VAR~FAC, 
          data=df, 
          FUN=\(x) df$DATE[which.max(x)])`. Find the row indexes of df where VAR is the max for each element of FAC and use that to a subset on DATE. That gives you the dates.

Comment: Oh, I see this now. This doesn't actually do what I want, because I have different numbers of dates for each group, and they aren't the same for each group. That's my mistake for simplifying the example too much. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `dplyr`, you can do -

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(FAC) %>% summarise(max_date = DATE[which.max(VAR)])
```

In `data.table` -

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(max_date = DATE[which.max(VAR)]), FAC]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    arrange(FAC, desc(VAR)) %>%
    group_by(FAC) %>%
    slice(1)
```